# Keras - layer.trainable = False to freeze layer doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, freeze

I'm training a RNN to classify three different classes. Because the accuracy of class 2 is very high I tried to train the RNN first to classify the two other classes, save the model, load the model, freeze the lower layers and then include class 2 again for training. Even after training over 4 epochs and freezing all layers the accuracy of class 2 is very high and the others are dropping again.

The model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True,
                       input_shape=(data.X_train.shape[1],
                                    data.X_train.shape[2])))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(4))
        model.add(Dense(data.y_test.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
```

Loading and freezing the first four layers:

```
        model = load_model(model_path)
        for layer in model.layers[:4]:
            layer.trainable = False
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=ad,
              metrics=['accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Can you check the weights of layers you froze before and after training?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I just checked the weights before and after training. They are all the same, so they are actually frozen.